# Linux terminal: How to pass an argument to another argument

Tags: java, linux, terminal, command-line-arguments

I have a system program that runs other programs in a special environment:
`cset shield -e PROGRAM`. Now to run a java program, I typed `cset shield -e java PROGRAM`, but that doesn't work. It turns out that I have to specify the full path of `java`. However, `PATH` is set, so on its own `java PROGRAM` works. Is there any easier way to do this?

In addition, another java program of mine requires external libraries and runs fine by itself. But with `cset shield`, I got `NoClassDefFoundError`, which means that it cannot find the libraries. Adding the classpath argument (`-cp CLASSPATH`) resulted in the error message `"p" contains invalid characters: p`.

---

After trying out the various suggestions and their permutations, I hit upon a way that half-works: `cset shield --exec -- $(which java) -cp ./:<LIB_PATH>/DA_LIB.jar PROGRAM`. But with this I'm getting `UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library not found: DA_LIB`

Comment: What is special about the environment that the 'cset' program runs other programs in?  It appears that whatever changes it makes are inimical to the running of Java.  It likely cleans out CLASSPATH and may damage PATH and perhaps LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  So, you need to study 'cset' (the manual pages or the source code or both) to understand what it does and why that causes you angst.

Comment: @Jonathan The manual says the following:

"Note that if your execed command takes options, then use the traditional "--" marker to separate cset’s options from your command’s options.

For example:

`# cset shield --exec — ls -l`

This command will execute "ls -l" inside the shield."

But while that allows me to run regular programs like `ls`, running java gives me `No such file or directory` error.

Comment: @wmjdgla: As @Jonathan Leffler indicated, it seems `cset shield` changes your environment, in particular `PATH` and `CLASSPATH` but probably also your current directory. If that is the case there is not much point in putting relative directories in your classpath. For instance you have `./` there, which is probably not of much use (since the current directory would be changed). I do not know what `<LIB_PATH>` is in your case, just make sure all paths are absolute.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `which` to locate java:

```
cset shield -e $(which java) PROGRAM
```

This will run java under the special environment, not in a sub shell. (`which` will run in a sub shell, obviously).

To fix the `CLASSPATH` issue: I cannot test it here but you probably can try this:

```
cset shield -e "$(which java) -cp <CLASSPATH> PROGRAM"
```

Where `<CLASSPATH>` needs to be replaced with the actual classpath.

Comment: That got rid of the need to specify the full path, but `NoClassDefFoundException` is still there. And I need to run it under the environment provided by `cset shield`, not a normal shell.

Comment: @wmjdgla: I have edited my answer to show what I would try to work around the `CLASSPATH` issue. Again the command will run under `cset shield`, not under the normal shell.

Comment: It now says `No such file or directory'.

Comment: I've added some new developments to my top post.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
cset shield -e `java PROGRAM`
```

Comment: Backticks run their content in a subshell and evaluate to the output of that command. This will not run java under the `cset shield` environment, rather it will run java under the normal environment and then try to run whatever java returns under `cset`.

Comment: I see, this isn't what I need then.

Answer (score 0):

```
cset shield -e $(java PROGRAM)
```

subshell $() seems to work better then backticks `` for shell substitution
(run command inside and return stdout)

for more info see

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html

Comment: But using a subshell means that I won't be running under the `cset shield` environment...

Comment: Sorry I mistook your question by looking at previous answer, you should still note that  $() is probably better `` for returning strings for a command you ran.